# How can I convert a console application to a .dll?

Tags: c#, dll, console

I am trying to convert an application written in C# to a DLL. The console application takes in input from the user and resets the password by calling a method of a service that I have imported in my project. How do I convert the console application into a DLL so that, whenever the user wishes to change their password, my DLL is invoked?

Comment: The "whenever the user wishes to change the password" requirement is **not** fulfilled by a DLL.  Type "RegisterHotKey" in the Search box at the upper right.

Answer (score 54):

Right-click Project -> Properties -> Application -> Output Type: 'Class Library'

[image]

Comment: Any idea how to do this with VS Code/dotnet CLI?

Comment: @Nomnom Just open the csproj file and change the `OutputType` to `Library`.