# Class Library is not referencable if it wasn't created as one initially. How to fix this problem and what might be the cause?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I have a project with a lot of classes, that was initially a console application, but then I decided to convert it into a class library. Whenever I use this method instead of creating a new project that is a class library in the first place, I am unable to import this class library to another project (I am able to include the reference within the project's reference panel though). The only other solution is to create a new project, create all classes manually, and copy-paste the code from the original project to the new class library classes. I want to be able to simply change the output type of the project to 'class-library' within the project properties and it to be import-able. The project is so big that copy-pasting everything is not an option and might break my code as well. Has anyone encountered this issue and knows the fix ?

Comment: have you removed the "Program.cs" file from the original console app?

Comment: @vhr Yes, I removed it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert a console application to a .dll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736628/how-can-i-convert-a-console-application-to-a-dll)

Comment: @OwenPauling How is that a duplicate ? I speciifically mentioned that I have tried that approach and my problem is completely different. That way doesn't work..

Answer (score 0):

This is my setup, ConsoleApp2 was originally created as console application. Can you check everything is the same? Also please check what is your target framework. I referenced the ConsoleApp2 dll directly (did not use a project reference).

[image]